# Prove $L_i(a_j)=\delta_{ij}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$ (Lagrange Interpolation)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ and $a_0,...,a_n$ real numbers all different. for $1\leq i\leq n$  Define $L_i \in V$ :

$L_i(x)=\prod_{j\not=i}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j} $

Prove $L_i(a_j)=\delta_{ij}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$

**Can someone give me a hint? 
I will be very grateful.**

Comment: Just substitute $a_j$ for $x$ in $L_i(x)$.

Comment: But that equal to $0... $ always. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Not when $j=i$.

Comment: TRUE @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for all (: all clear.